# Angular Material Expansion Panel on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have followed the following example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-open-close-panel-by-button-material-accordion?

but in this example, when we manually close the accordion, and when clicked on the same button it is not opening.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The reason is that the value doesn't change in that specific scenario (e.g. you clicked button 2, closed panel 2 and clicked button 2 again), therefore the binding is not updating (no change detected for activePanel in expansion-overview). You could go with a service that emits a value (use `BehaviorSubject`), but you also need to change `panelState` in the panels when you close them by clicking the panel (otherwise panelState will stay true leading to no change detection again).

Comment: as Gunnar said change is not getting detected so it is not updating the panel state to true. you could try to reset the activePanel when panel is collapsed using closed event on mat-expansion-panel. updated sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-open-close-panel-by-button-material-accord-ku8qw5?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

Comment: @mahindar your changes are reverted in the sample I guess

Comment: @Shinchan sorry I guess I pasted the wrong link. If you are still looking for this here is the working one https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-open-close-panel-by-button-material-accord-5dbrwk?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html